# select the maximum value from array python

Tags: python, arrays, list, max

How to get the sublist with the maximum length within a list?

I have this codes:

```
c = [1,2]
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]
for b in a:
    g = len(list(set(b) - set(c))) *#list of difference items between c and b in a*
    print(g)
```

result

```
0
2
1
```

I need to get `b` in `a` with the longest length >> `g = 2`

I used

```
y = [b for b in a if max (g)]
```

*`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`*

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`max(g)` doesn't really make much sense because `g` is just the last `int` value (`1`) in the previous loop. `max()` expects an iterable - hence your error. But even fixing `g` to be the list `[0, 2, 1]` your guard in the list comprehension wouldn't really do anything because it would always evaluate to `True` because it is equivalent to writing `if 2`.

But you can rewrite your code with `max()` using the `key` to calculate the difference:

```
>>> c = [1,2]
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]
>>> max(a, key=lambda x: len(set(x)-set(c)))
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
c = [1,2]
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [3,2]]
k=max(max(map(lambda x:set(c)-set(x),a)))
print k if k else 0
```